# Consumir Web Reference C#

Tags: c#, web-service

Gostaria de uma ajuda de Vocês

Adicionei o Serviço via Web Reference

```
NFSeBeloHorizonteMG.NfseWSService ws1 = new NFSeBeloHorizonteMG.NfseWSService();

ws1.Url = hostWS;

X509Certificate certificado = cert.BuscaNroSerie(noSerieCert, false);
ws1.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
ws1.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

string result = ws1.ConsultarLoteRps(cabecalho, consulta);
```

quando ele chega na ConsultarLoteRPS ele da o erro

A Solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS.

Estou tendo esse mesmo problema em outros serviço

não é certificado pois alguns serviço funciona normalmente com este certificado

Comment: o erro acontece no localhost ou só quando você publica? O cerficado está instalado no servidor e você está fazendo a requisição a partir de um ambiente seguro, https/ssl?

Comment: A aplicação e desktop, o certificado esta instalado na maquina e estou tentando acessar o serviço nfse de belo horizonte

Comment: Consegui resolver atualizando meu Visual Studio para 2010 e utilizando o Service Reference

Comment: Legal, qual é o visual studio que estava usando antes?

Comment: Visual Studio 2005